# SQL Server: Safely moving data to a (badly maintained) history table

Tags: sql-server

The company I just started working for has a table and a history table for it. However the history table was badly maintained, so it is not identical to the original.

One of the problems is that the history table's columns are in a different order (though they do have the same name). Another is that some columns are missing.

Currently once a year the data from the table is moved to the history with a query like (delete statement omitted):

```
insert into my_history_table (a, b, c)
select a, b, c from my_table;
```

The table has over a hundred columns, so specifying all names is tedious and error prone. Also if someone changes the table, but not the history table nor the procedure to move the values, values will get lost without any error. That has happened a lot, and I'm trying to prevent that in the future.

So, is it possible to move data from one table to another, based on the column names rather than their position, and simultaniously check if they are consistent?

The query

```
insert into my_history_table
select * from my_table;
```

inserts based on position, and gives an error when there are incompatible types or missing columns. However, if two compatible columns (for instance both int) swapped place, it will work but data will end up in the wrong column.

Sadly I can't ensure noone will change the original table behind my back, but I can pretty much guarantee that whoever does change that table won't update the query and history table accordingly. Since this query it run only once a year, it would be nice that it gave an error if the history table needs updating.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: You could look into storing the row in JSON instead. Why don't you just copy the whole table, or backup the database instead? What is your actual use case for this table? Seems like there would be a better solution

Comment: Not sure if it can be done with only SQL, but you could write a script that uses the system tables to compare the tables and repair the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build you insert string dynamically such as:

```
CREATE TABLE ProdTable(id int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)
CREATE TABLE HistoryTable(id int, col3 int, col1 int, col2 int)


IF EXISTS(
SELECT Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'ProdTable'
EXCEPT
SELECT Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'HistoryTable')

RAISERROR( 'THERE ARE COLUMNS IN THE MAIN TABLE THAT DO NOT EXIST IN THE HISTORY TABLE', 16,1)

DECLARE @COL_NAME varchar(40)
DECLARE @INSERT_STRING varchar(max)
DECLARE @SELECT_STRING varchar(max)

SET @INSERT_STRING = 'INSERT INTO HistoryTable('
SET @SELECT_STRING = ' SELECT '

DECLARE csr CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY  for
SELECT Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'HistoryTable'

OPEN csr
FETCH csr INTO @COL_NAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @INSERT_STRING = @INSERT_STRING + '[' + @COL_NAME + '],'
SET @SELECT_STRING = @SELECT_STRING + '[' + @COL_NAME + '],'
FETCH csr INTO @COL_NAME
END
CLOSE csr
DEALLOCATE csr

SET @INSERT_STRING = SUBSTRING(@INSERT_STRING,0,LEN(@INSERT_STRING))
SET @SELECT_STRING = SUBSTRING(@SELECT_STRING,0,LEN(@SELECT_STRING))

SET @INSERT_STRING = @INSERT_STRING + ') ' + CHAR(10)  + @SELECT_STRING + ' FROM ProdTable ' 

PRINT @INSERT_STRING
```

If you want to see it throw the error then just add another column to the ProdTable:

```
ALTER TABLE ProdTable ADD  col4 INT
```

Just cut and paste the built string from the messages tab into another query window and you should be good to go.  Obviously if you are doing a large number of rows you should do it in batches....but that is another thread.

**EDIT:**

You could probably do away with the cursor and just use a FOR XML:

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'ProdTable'
EXCEPT
SELECT Column_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'HistoryTable')

RAISERROR( 'THERE ARE COLUMNS IN THE MAIN TABLE THAT DO NOT EXIST IN THE HISTORY TABLE', 16,1)

DECLARE @COL_NAMES varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @INSERT_STRING varchar(max)

SELECT @COL_NAMES =  (SELECT  '[' + Column_Name + '],'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'HistoryTable'
FOR XML PATH(''))

SET @COL_NAMES = SUBSTRING(@COL_NAMES,0,LEN(@COL_NAMES))
SET @INSERT_STRING = 'INSERT INTO HistoryTable(' + @COL_NAMES + ') ' + CHAR(10)  +   ' SELECT ' + @COL_NAMES  + ' FROM ProdTable ' 

PRINT @INSERT_STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to here.I had similar requirement and i have implemented both in different cases.

1. Use C#.NET SQLBulkCopy class, Which provides this feature of mapping column on basis of column name.
2. Dynamic Query. Below is a rough pseudocode.

   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   Where TABLE_NAME = 'MainTable'

   While 'Parse each Source Column'
   Begin
    SELECT @Col FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    Where TABLE_NAME = 'History Table' and ColumnName = 'MainTableColumn'

   If @Col is not null
    BEGIN
     string @ColumnList + = @Col
    END

   --Then develop dynamic query like below

   INSERT INTO HistoryTable (@ColumnList) 
    SELECT @ColumnList FROM MainTable

   END

Answer (score -1):

Please use trigger instead of directly inserting data in history table.
Use trigger, so that if any DML operation will get executed trigger will automatically insert data in History table with help of magic tables.

Comment: Ah, I might have misworded this, when the data is copied it is also removed from the original table. So once a year a copy happens, and the original table is cleared as well. I'll specify this in the original question too.

Comment: Please don't do this, Tiggers are a recipe for disaster

Comment: Same here i wont suggest triggers, for history logging.